# Best practice for linking images/files in different web folders

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Probably title don't make any sense , so i will explain my problem in details.

Lets say i have www.mysite.com , where i have background image for div , onclick() , div changes background image. Everything is working just fine. Problems start, when i have subfolder, for example, myblog. It looks like www.example/myblog/post1.php . In post1 i got same div with same backgrounds, but onclick it doesnt work, because link is targeting img, which don't exist.

In first case jquery do it all right : www.mysite.com/assets/img/picture.jpg (this is actual location)

In second  case jquery is adding folowing link : www.mysite.com/**myblog**/assets/img/picture.jpg
code is simple, as u imagine. onclick do

```
$('#div').css("background-image", "url("assets/img/picture.jpg")");
```

so , things work when i add ../assets/img/picture.jpg , but then it wont work in root directory.

i have tried using url+assets/img/picture.jpg , but i get www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com/...etc
(and yes url is correct).

So my question is, how to deal with this problem? Same goes for includes like header and footer. if i have "include" folder on root, i cant link to it if i am in /blog/post1.php . I have been struggling with this for a while, so i would like to get some tips.

If it makes any difference, i am working in codeigniter....

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I'll print a file reference into a page, I print it relatively to the root address:

To include the file `http://mysite.com/assets/img/picture.jpg`, I would use the `/assets/img/picture.jpg` reference. So the browser will look for this file starting from the root (`/`) page.

This will be a problem if you move your entire website to another folder. That's why I always keep a global setting for every application I make, the "path" setting.

E.g. the application http://mysite.com/app1/ has the "path" setting = "app1". When I'll print a file reference to a page, I take this setting into consideration, like:

```
$file_path = "assets/img/picture.jpg";    
echo "/$site_path/$file_path";
```

This will print `/app1/assets/img/picture.jpg`. If for some reason I need to make another install of this application in http://mysite2.com/anotherappname/, I just change the global path setting to "anotherappname.

Comment: ok, thats for includes in php files.... but how i can manage it in Jquery file with css actions?  As i mentioned, i got /assets or ../assets . Do i need make two conditions, or there is easy way around  ?

Comment: As I mentioned, if you add a / before the path, no matter where the script loads, it will look from the website root.

`$('#div').css("background-image", "url('/assets/img/picture.jpg')");`

will always look in http://mysite.com/assets/img/picture.jpg, no matter if you are inside a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I normally set a variable of `$domain` in PHP which looks something like `http://www.example.com/` (notice the trailing slash). I then `echo` this to a Javascript variable like so:

```
<script>
var domain = '<?php echo $domain; ?>';
</script>
```

This variable is then available in Javascript too. I might use it like this:

```
<script>
$('#div').css("background-image", "url('" +domain + "assets/img/picture.jpg')");
</script>
```

If you need to change `$domain` then the changes will trickle through to your Javascript which is handy.

Comment: im going with


     pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];
url = protocol + '://' + host;

then add url variable instead of your domain, but it is the same thing ( i hope ) but as i mentioned in topic, i get url(http://www.mysite.lv/blog/://www.mysite.lv/assets/img/picture.jpg); in inspect element
}

Comment: @Merkley: `window.location` has already `protocol`, `host` and `pathname` properties saved.